# show data on dropdown textchange in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which i have a dropdownlist and 3 options (`1 default 2 Hotel/school 3 Date`) when my pageloads `Default` option is selected and sql records are shown

now when user change from `default` to `Hotel/school or Date` then re select `default` i want to show the records of pageload

here what i did in `js`

```
//textchange to default
        if($scope.drd=="drd='Default'")
        {
            $scope.names = '';
            $scope.loadimage = true;
            $http.get('/csuv5.asmx/pageload', {
                params: {
                    log: log,
                    pm: pm
                }
            })

            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.loadimage = false;
                $scope.sonvinrpm = response.data.page;
                //pagination
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.sonvinrpm.length;
                $scope.numPerPage = 5;
                $scope.paginate = function (value) {
                    var begin, end, index;
                    begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
                    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                    index = $scope.sonvinrpm.indexOf(value);
                    return (begin <= index && index < end);
                };
                console.log(response.data.page);
            });
        };
```

any idea about how it needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-change="fetchData()" ng-model="drd">
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="holelSchool">Hotel/school</option>
    <option value="date">Date/school</option>
</select>
```

Where $scope.fetchData() is a wrapper for your $http

Comment: what about my js file